# How to configure vim for quickfix

Tags: vim

I am getting the following error:

```
/bin/bash: ccfilter: command not found
```

when I issue the `:make` command in vim.  I need to install (or build) the `ccfilter` binary but I can't find it.  Where can I find it?  I looked in `/usr/share/vim` and I didn't see it.

This is for Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Did you check the current directory?

Comment: `ccfilter` should be distributed with vim.  I've had to build it from a `.c` file before but I can't find it for this distro.

Comment: Whoops, my bad, I misunderstood your post. So you're saying ccfilter has nothing to do with what your compiling, but rather it is a dependency of vim's make command?

Comment: Correct.  It formats the error messages so that vim can process them.

Comment: It used to part of the `vim-runtime` package, but it no longer is.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why.  The quickfix feature of vim is useless without it.

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but did you try `locate ccfilter`?

Comment: Yeah, I did it before and I just double-checked now.  No joy.

Comment: You don't need ccfilter to use Vim's quickfix feature. I've used Vim's `:make` command for many years and have never used ccfilter. The default 'errorformat' works fine for the compilers I use, usually gcc. `ccfilter` is not even mentioned in Vim's documentation any more, at least it isn't for Vim 7.2 and 7.4. I would just use the default 'shellpipe' and see how `:make` works then. (The ccfilter man page in /usr/share/vim/vim7[234]/tools/ says that ccfilter is used by including it in 'shellpipe', so I assume your ~/.vimrc includes that setting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need `ccfilter` to use `:make`. `ccfilter` seems to date from Vim 5. There is no mention of it in the current Vim documentation except for a filename change noted in version5.txt.

The default setting of the '`errorformat`' option should work for many compilers. You can also use the `:compiler` command with the name of your compiler to optimize '`errorformat`' for that compiler. If you have an uncommon compiler, you may need set the value '`errorformat`' yourself to get something that works well for you. Finding the value of '`errorformat`' for an unsupported compiler is not straightforward, but it's not hard--it just takes some fiddling and experimentation.

The `:make` command does not use `ccfilter` by default. The error message you're seeing suggests that one of your configuration files is telling Vim to use `ccfilter`. The `ccfilter` man page, found in $VIMFILES/tools/ccfilter.1 in distributions that include it, suggests using `ccfilter` as follows.

```
:set shellpipe=\|&ccfilter\>
```

So, when you see that error message, you could execute

```
:verbose set shellpipe?
```

which will show you where '`shellpipe`' was last set. Edit that file and remove that line. There may be a line like the following nearby.

```
:set errorformat=%f:%l:%c:%t:%m
```

Remove that line, too, so that Vim can use its default '`errorformat`'.

That should fix the problem.

You can find out more about using `:make` here.

```
:help 30.1
:help :make
:help compiler-select
:help errorformats
```